# Where is <libraryname>.pc?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, libraries, directory-structure, dynamic-linking

1. When installing a library with `configure`, `make` and `make install`,
   does `make install` copy `<libraryname>.pc` to some place?

   - If yes: Where is it?
   - If no: Should we copy it somewhere rather than leave them where they are?
2. I am asking that, because on an old notebook of mine, I saw:

   > add the directory containing `libraryname.pc` to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable, so that `pkg-config --clags libraryname` and `pkg-config --libs libraryname` can find them.
3. Will `dpkg -l` be able to track the installed library depending on whether  it's path was added to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`?
4. Once I copy `<libraryname>.pc` to some place, will `dpkg -l` be
   able to track the installed packages?

Comment: Please don't combine multiple questions in a single post. `dpkg` has nothing to do with packages you install manually from source.

Comment: Also where on your old note(book) did you see the quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, `./configure && make && make install` without any parameters sticks everything under `/usr/local`, which would place `foo.pc` in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/foo.pc`

To make use of this, you'd need to do basically `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH} pkg-config --cflags foo`, or, compile in this manner:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr #places built binaries under /usr instead of /usr/local
make
make install
```

Now the `foo.pc` file will be where its expected.

Note: This places stuff in system folders, so realize you can overwrite important things if you're not careful.

And to answer regarding the `dpkg` question, no. Package managers can only track files installed by them. Now, if you're feeling adventureous, you can write up the files needed to wrap the standard `./configure && make && make install` buils process to produce a `dpkg` installable deb package, which *would* be tracked :)

Its been some time since I last made a debian package, a few years, and to be honest I rather hated the process, so don't expect info from me on that front. I've since switched to archlinux and writing `PKGBUILD`s (scripts that build arch packages using `makepkg`) is quite a simple task :)